# Как открывать выпадающее меню в бок по центру

Tags: html, css

Подскажите, что использовать чтобы меню выводилось не вниз лесенкой, а просто влево. Как например, на сайте [ситилинк](https://www.citilink.ru/) или [робокассы](http://market.robokassa.ru/category/autochemicalgoods-31)

**UPD**: убрал `position: relative` для `.menu ul li`, меню выводится правильно, но теперь если в нижнем меню мало пунктов, то нет возможности навести курсор на них. Код Исправил. Можно ли расширить область для `.submenu`?

Имею такое меню:

```css
html,*{
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
font-size: 16px;
}

body{
background: #eee;
}
a{
text-decoration: none;
}
.menu {
  z-index: 100;
  width: 230px;
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  background: #fff;
}

.menu ul{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}
.menu ul li{
  display: block;
  border-bottom: #ccc 1px solid;
 }
.menu ul li a{
  display: block;
  color: #000;
  padding: 5px;
}

.menu ul li.active > a,
.menu ul li a:hover{
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
  background: #ccc;
}


.menu ul li .submenu{
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 100%;
  background: #ddd;
}

.menu ul li:hover > .submenu{
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="menu">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Sample</a></li>
        <li class="active"><a href="">Sample</a>
          <ul class="submenu submenu1">
            <li><a href="#">Sub</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Sub</a></li>
            <li class="active"><a href="">Sub</a>
              <ul class="submenu submenu2">
                <li><a href="#">Sub</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Sub</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Sub</a></li>
                <li class="active"><a href="">Sub</a>
                  <ul class="submenu submenu3">
                    <li><a href="#">Sub</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Sub</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Sub</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Sub</a></li>
                    <li class="active"><a href="">Sub</a></li>
                  </ul><!--// Inner Child 3 -->
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Sub</a></li>
              </ul><!--// Inner Child 2 -->
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Sub</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Sub</a></li>
          </ul><!--// Inner Child 1 -->
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Sample</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Sample</a></li>
        <li class="active><a href="#">Sample</a>
          <ul class="submenu submenu3">
                    <li><a href="#">Sub</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Sub</a></li>
            </ul><!--// Inner Child 3 -->
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div><!--// end .menu -->
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Убрать у `.menu ul li` `position: relative`.

**UPD**: добавить `min-height: 100%` для `.submenu`.

```css
html,
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-size: 16px;
}

body {
  background: #eee;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.menu {
  z-index: 100;
  width: 230px;
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  background: #fff;
}

.menu ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

.menu ul li {
  display: block;
  border-bottom: #ccc 1px solid;
  /*position: relative;*/
}

.menu ul li a {
  display: block;
  color: #000;
  padding: 5px;
}

.menu ul li.active>a,
.menu ul li a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
  background: #ccc;
}

.menu ul li .submenu {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 100%;
  background: #ddd;
}

.menu ul li:hover>.submenu {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="menu">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Sample</a></li>
    <li class="active"><a href="">Sample</a>
      <ul class="submenu submenu1">
        <li><a href="#">Sub</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Sub</a></li>
        <li class="active"><a href="">Sub</a>
          <ul class="submenu submenu2">
            <li><a href="#">Sub</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Sub</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Sub</a></li>
            <li class="active"><a href="">Sub</a>
              <ul class="submenu submenu3">
                <li><a href="#">Sub</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Sub</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Sub</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Sub</a></li>
                <li class="active"><a href="">Sub</a></li>
              </ul>
              <!--// Inner Child 3 -->
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Sub</a></li>
          </ul>
          <!--// Inner Child 2 -->
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Sub</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Sub</a></li>
      </ul>
      <!--// Inner Child 1 -->
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Sample</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Sample</a></li>
    <li class="active"><a href="#">Sample</a>
      <ul class="submenu submenu3">
        <li><a href="#">Sub</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Sub</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
<!--// end .menu -->
```

Comment: При этом, если у меня в нижнем меню будет всего два элемента, то достать я их не смогу (я исправил код в вопросе). Подскажите как можно решить эту проблему? расширить область

Comment: см. обновленный ответ.

Comment: Большое спасибо